# How do I compare two values in SQLite from different tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to make a `where` clause from a different table with 2 values in match for example in *SQLite*.

**Table 1:**

```
Date|CID|text
1/1/90 22:22:22 1 hi
1/1/90 21:22:30 1 How are you
1/1/90 03:22:22 3 hey
```

**Table 2:**

```
ID|date|CID|text
100 1/1/89 11:22:11 1 hello
200 1/1/90 22:22:22 1 hi
300 1/1/90 21:22:30 1 How are you
400 1/1/90 03:22:22 3 hey
500 1/1/85 02:22:22 3 hey
600 1/1/90 03:22:22 80 hey
```

How to make the query give me the `ID` from table 2 matching the `CID` and `date` from table 1?

Note: If I use `where` *in* the result and some date matches in the case of `ID` 600 and 400, the result will be on the query and I'm not looking that.

Just matching `CID` and `date` from table 1 should be listed in the result.

Comment: What have you tried? Looking at your attempt will give people a better idea of the exact problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can want a `join` with two conditions

```
select t1.*, t2.id
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.cid and t1.date = t2.date;
```

If you want to keep all rows in `table1`, even those with no matches, then use a `left join` instead.